# Covariance between two sets of random variables.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

I am trying to analyze the correlation between two sets of random variables. In particular, consider the disjoint sets of random variables $\mathcal{A}=\left\{ A_{0},\dots,A_{n_{a}-1}\right\} $
and $\mathcal{B}=\left\{ B_{0},\dots,B_{n_{b}-1}\right\} $, define
their union set as $\mathcal{C}\equiv\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B}$, then the
covariance matrix of the random variables in $\mathcal{C}$ can be
written as:

\begin{align*}
{\rm Cov}\left(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{C}\right) & \equiv\begin{pmatrix}{\rm Cov}\left(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{A}\right) & {\rm Cov}\left(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}\right)\\
{\rm Cov}\left(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}\right) & {\rm Cov}\left(\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B}\right)
\end{pmatrix},\\
{\rm Cov}\left(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{F}\right)_{ij} & \equiv{\rm Cov}\left(D_{i},F_{j}\right),D_{i}\in\mathcal{D}\text{ and }F_{j}\in\mathcal{F}.
\end{align*}

here ${\rm Cov}\left(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{A}\right),{\rm Cov}\left(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}\right)$
and ${\rm Cov}\left(\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B}\right)$ are covariances
matrices. Given that we know the matrix ${\rm Cov}\left(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{C}\right)$, is there any systematic criteria to characterize the correlation between the sets $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$?

I tried to compare the eigenvalues of ${\rm Cov}\left(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{C}\right)$, and ${\rm Cov}\left(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{A}\right)$ and ${\rm Cov}\left(\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B}\right)$, and if there is no correlation between $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ then the spectrum ${\rm Cov}\left(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{C}\right)$ is equal to the union of the spectrum of ${\rm Cov}\left(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{A}\right)$ and ${\rm Cov}\left(\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B}\right)$. I want to know if there is a better way to quantify the correlation between the sets $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation might be what you want

Comment: Nice reference, thanks. I am just wondering yet how to quantify how suitable is to separate the set $\mathcal{C}$ into the disjoint sets $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ for describing the system.

Comment: I would try using $\sum \rho_i$ (there the $\rho_i$ are as in the CCA wikipedia article) as a kind of surrogate for the number of "shared" variables between the A and B sets.

Comment: For gaussian variables it was shown in a previous question that there is a form to quantify the correlation between the partition of random variables https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438607/mutual-information-between-subsets-of-variables-in-the-multivariate-normal-distr